# Android Video Recording without using android media recorder

Tags: android, android-camera, surfaceview, mediarecorder

is there anyway to record video without using mediaRecorder..

if there is no other way how can i preview camera into the media recorder before start video recording ..

Comment: "is there anyway to record video without using mediaRecorder" -- not really. You are welcome to capture preview frames and somehow stitch them together into a video. Vine used this approach, IIRC, at least a few years ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Camera google API you must set a MediaRecorder or a MediaCodec surface to be able to create a video Capture session for video. Setting the surface of the video:

```
createCameraPreviewSession(mMediaRecorder.getSurface(),
                mFrameRate,
                mVideoSize,
                mSize,
                mRetry);
```

In [Android developer webpage](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraDevice.html#createCaptureSession(java.util.List%3Candroid.view.Surface%3E,%20android.hardware.camera2.CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback,%20android.os.Handler)) you can see the both ways to record a video. MediaCodec or MediaRecorder:

> For recording with MediaCodec: Call createInputSurface() after configuring the media codec to use one of the sizes returned by getOutputSizes(MediaCodec.class)
>
> For recording with MediaRecorder: Call getSurface() after configuring
>   the media recorder to use one of the sizes returned by
>   getOutputSizes(MediaRecorder.class), or configuring it to use one of
>   the supported CamcorderProfiles.

Comment: Thank you very much